# Write a const pattern to a file of specific size

Tags: c++, io, fstream, binaryfiles

I need to write C++ code that will open a binary file and will write 5 MB of '1' in to it.

Currently my code is:

```
#define BYTES_BUFFER_SIZE_5MB (1024*1024*5)

static char buffer[BYTES_BUFFER_SIZE_5MB];
memset(buffer, 0xff, BYTES_BUFFER_SIZE_5MB);
ofstream myFile ("data.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
myFile.write(buffer, BYTES_BUFFER_SIZE_5MB);
```

Is there a `memset`-like method for writing to a file, so I can avoid having a buffer?

Comment: `1024*1024*5` = merry hell if you have a 16 bit `int`. You have to be very careful with compile time evaluable constant expressions.

Comment: A nice feature of using a large buffer is that the system can process the data transfer in the background.  For example, the driver could use a DMA processor to transfer the data to the hard drive.  The relieves the CPU of having to read memory, write data to the device, repeat.

Comment: There is an overhead to each transaction.  The optimal solution is to maximize data sizes per transaction.  The overhead could be: drive spinning up, drive spinning down, locating sectors, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think we can do this in one line with stream manipulators:

```
fout << std::setw(BYTES_BUFFER_SIZE_5MB - 1) << std::setfill(char(0xFF)) << char(0xFF);
```

- [`setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) to set the number of bytes to write out
- [`setfill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) to make it write out 0xFF by default

That way we don't have a buffer involved. The only risk is if you want to write a lot of bytes, you risk overflowing `int` on your call to `setw`.

Comment: It should be noted that you can use a compile time value for the size sent to setw, making this useful for padding out binary structures when writing them to files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a smaller buffer and write it several times with a `for` loop.

If you have to write 5Mb you can do something like

```
#define BYTES_SIZE_5MB (5242880) // Bathsheba comment have to be considered
#define BUFFER_SIZE (1024) // Chunk size to be written (this is an arbitrary amount)

static char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
ofstream myFile ("data.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
int i, repetitions = BYTES_SIZE_5MB / BUFFER_SIZE;
memset(buffer, 0xff, BUFFER_SIZE);
for (i=0; i < repetitions; ++i)
    myFile.write(buffer, BYTES_BUFFER_SIZE_5MB);
myFile.close();
```

**Note** `write()` method could become really slow, it's better to choose a bigger *chunk size* and that way you will do less `write` calls, which improves the speed of your program

Answer (score 0):

It's not simpler, but you can use [memory-mapped files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file). They give you exactly what you asked for - you can write the file as if you're writing to memory.

Each (popular) operating system have different API for them, but there are a few libraries that provide portable support.